# How to use an Array List in place of a HashMap in Android?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails-4

I have used have used a Hashmap to send a Post request using Volley by

```
 protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("message",message);
                    return params;
                }
```

I now wish to pass an array of user sign up details to a Rails controller in the form of

```
"user"=>{"name"=>"jackson", "email"=>"jack@yahoo.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}
```

When I try using a Hashmap only to make the Post request I get the error

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: user):
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:73:in `user_params'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:21:in `create'
```

Because the Hashmap sends the data as

```
{"name"=>"jackson", "email"=>"jack@yahoo.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}
```

My question is how can I use an ArrayList in this case to accomplish the correct format of user details?

Below is my entire code for reference.

```
public class Register extends Activity {

Button btnLogin;
EditText inputUsername;
EditText inputEmail;
EditText inputPassword;
EditText inputPasswordConfirmation;

private List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();

public class User {

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String password_confirmation;

     public User() {
        }

        public User(String name, String email, String password, String password_confirmation) {
            this.name = name;
            this.email = email;
            this.password = password;
            this.password_confirmation = password_confirmation;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        public String getPasswordConfirmation() {
            return password_confirmation;
        }

        public void setPasswordConfirmation(String password_confirmation) {
            this.password_confirmation = password_confirmation;
        }

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fld_username);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fld_email);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fld_pwd);
    inputPasswordConfirmation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fld_pwd_confirm);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

    final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final User user = new User();
            user.setName(String.valueOf(inputUsername.getText()));
            user.setEmail(String.valueOf(inputEmail.getText()));
            user.setPassword(String.valueOf(inputPassword.getText()));
            user.setPasswordConfirmation(String.valueOf(inputPasswordConfirmation.getText()));



            StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                    "http://community.ngrok.com/users", new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String s) {
                    Log.d("Response", s);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    Log.d("Error",volleyError.toString());
                }
            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                   ArrayList<String> params = new ArrayList<String>();
                    params.add(user.getName());
                    params.add(user.getEmail());
                    params.add(user.getPassword());
                    params.add(user.getPasswordConfirmation());

                    return params;
                }
            };

            queue.add(postRequest);

            Intent home = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(home);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You need another level of key/value pairs.

Comment: A list and a map are two different things, you can't *convert* one to the other. As Dave Newton points out, you're missing a level in your map.

Comment: I have such the class implementation but I the part I can't get to work is the Hashmap part how do I write "Put user.email" instead of just email

Answer (score 0):

Create a bean class like this , its easy and oops approach

```
public class UserInformation {

    private String mUserId = "";
    private String mName = "";


    public String getmUserId() {
        return mUserId;
    }

    public void setmUserId(String mUserId) {
        this.mUserId = mUserId;
    }

    public String getmName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setmName(String mName) {
        this.mName = mName;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of putting values in themap, create a class liek this

```
class UserInfo{
      private String name;
      private String email;
```

and so on

and put this in the volley request parameter against the key of 'user'

Comment: I have such a class but where I cant seem to figure out is the bit at `protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put("message",email);
                        return params;`